# mysql query result order issue

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a table with these fields: userid, logintime, birthdate
I need to get ALL users between birthdate X and Y ordered with the most recently logged in first.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE birtdate BETWEEN x AND Y 
ORDER BY logintime DESC
```

If I defined an index on just birtdate, mysql would use filesort to order the results which I would like to avoid (table is getting big, query is popular).
Defining an index (logintime, birthdate) doesn't make sense to me since logintime isn't even in the WHERE clause (I'm only restricting the result set by birthdate)

Any elegant solutions in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Adding index on `birthdate,logintime` should improve your query, but it has its downside. I believe `logintime`(as its name implies) changes frequently, so db engine has to update the underlying index which in turn will cause index fragmentation.
 I don't see a big problem with filesort if your query is selective enough and an index on `birthdate` is used.
 Also, you can try putting your query in the body of stored procedure; in this case, mysql will use cache more effectively compared to ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 0):

The index have to be birtdate, longtime (first you have to satisfy the WHERE clause, then the order), but I'm not sure it can use index for sorting with between condition. How many records it needs to sort? As Query is popular, you can use memcache or another caching mechanism to serve the results without hitting the database

Comment: At the moment the index is only on birthdate but the filesort is starting the bog the database down. Index is used for BETWEEN, so that isn't a problem. I was hoping there would be a solution in mysql that wouldn't require add-ons (memcache) etc.

Comment: would you try indexing birtdate,logintime (as stated above, the order matters, index on logintime,birtdate can't satisfy query)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, having an index on a column has no effect of *sorting*, only on *searching* - it helps the *where* clause, not the *order by* clause.

EDIT: Follow @Darhazer's link - essentially is says "ORDER BY can be satisfied by an index"

Comment: An index can help in searching, sorting and grouping results.

Comment: @Bohemian read [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)